# Apply the inverse Laplace transform on expression

Tags: laplace-transform

**Problem**:Apply the inverse Laplace method to this expression:
$F(p)=\frac{3p+7}{p^3}$

**My Question**:
I know how to solve this and the right anwser to this problem. But I don't understand what rule is being used in the first step:
$$3L^{-1}\{\frac{p}{p^3}\}+7L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{p^3}\}$$

I dont understand why we can write $L^{-1}\{\frac{p}{p^3}\}$ as $L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{p^3}\}$ for the first transform. I mean why not $L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{p^2}\}$ Why can we ignore p in numerator and write it as 1? What rule is being applied here? Can you, please, explain or give the name for this rule? I don't understand only this part of the problem... The anwser is $3t+\frac{7t^2}{2}$

**Update**: Due to confusion I repeat that
I am not asking about splitting a fraction I ask about transforming first fraction (which is $p/p^3$) and why we write it as $1/p^3$ and not $1/p^2$. I understand how and why we split the $(3p+7)/p^3$.

**Update2**: The part of the question is this expression: $3L^{-1}\{\frac{p}{p^3}\}$. The right approach is to write it as $3L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{p^3}\}$ and the multiply by $\frac{2}{2}$ to get $L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{p^3}\}$, where $\frac{2}{p^3}$ is the table value. I dont understand why we write $p^3$ as denominator of this fraction and not $p^2$.

**Update3**: if $\frac{p}{p^3}=\frac{1}{p^2}$ why do we write it as $\frac{1}{p^3}$?

Comment: Have you posted the whole first step? I don't see $\frac{2}{p^3}$ anywhere in what you've got.

Comment: I ask about why we write p/p^3 as 1/p^3 and not 1/p^2

Comment: The expression is equivalent to ${ 3 \over p^2 }+ {7 \over p^3}$, so yes, you can split it and it is for the form ${1 \over p^2}$. I don't know where you are getting the ${1 \over 2}$ and ${2 \over p^3}$ parts from?

Comment: My table says that $$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^{n}}\right)=\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!},\;n=1,2,3,\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Laplace and Inverse Laplace Transforms are linear operators, such that $$L^{-1}(c)(a+b)=(c)L^{-1}(a)+(c)L^{-1}(b)$$
In your probelm, the fraction is merely split apart and evaluated.

Comment: I am not asking about splitting a fraction. I ask about transforming first fraction (which is p/p^3) and why we write it as 1/p^3 and not 1/p^2. I understand how and why we split the (3p+7)/p^3.

Comment: Seems to be a mistake because that is not right.

Comment: @ViktorK WHO writes $1/p^3$ instead of $1/p^2$???

Answer (score 0):

Check your understanding of fractions: the only rule being used here is that
$\frac{3p+7}{p^3} = \frac{3p}{p^3} + \frac{7}{p^3}$, and then linearity of the Laplace transform.

Comment: that is not what I ask

Comment: Could you write in your question the entirety of the step you don't understand?

Comment: update2 explains it more clearly